# BACKUP CASSANDRA

Tags: nosql, backup, cassandra

Estou fazendo um backup em um cluster cassandra com 6 nós. Estamos trabalhando com fator de consistencia 3.

Preciso fazer backup de todos os nós? Ou o backup seria interessante apenas em um dos nós, já que as informações estariam nos 6 nós existentes? Há alguma estratégia para ser usada neste caso.

Simplesmente eu atualmente tenho feito um nodetool snapshot e copiado as pastas geradas para um midia externa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa fazer backup de todos os nós, porque o Cassandra impedirá que os nós tenham as mesmas informações. Isso é obtido com a distribuição de tokens e é definido com o argumento "num_tokens".

Você também deve considerar que apenas manter uma cópia dos dados não garante precisão, pois Cassandra possui consistência eventual; isso significa que, se você mantiver uma cópia que não recebeu uma atualização ou antes de ser reparada, perderá informações.